# Нужно что-то вроде AUTO_INCREMENT в MySQL...

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте...

Как сделать так, чтобы создание нового идентификатора начиналось с первого пустого, а не с заданного, как в случае с AUTO_INCREMENT в MySQL...

Нужно, чтобы начиналось с первого пустого и пропускало существующие записи..

Comment: Дело в том, допустим добавляются записи с id 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
Через некоторое время записи с 3 и 4 я удаляю...
Я хочу, Чтобы когда я потом буду добавлять записи, нумерация id начиналась с 3.. Когда опять добавляю запись - с 4... затем с 8, 9
Тоесть с первого не занятого id

Comment: Это бред, конечно, и зачем это нужно, вам не нравятся числа больше миллиона? :)

Comment: Ну да )...

Comment: Зачем вам это?

Comment: Забейте, вы этих чисел всё равно не видите и не считаете их сами, оставьте ты эту идею, ибо она, если посмотрите по комментариям смешная.

Comment: Единственно правильный ответ - смирись и не заморачивайся :)

Answer (score 2):

Вы не первый, кто этим заболевает - раздражает, что ,так сказать "пустые места" в таблице ))) Переболеете ;)
Дело в том, что суть автоинкремента и состоит в том, чтоб уникальные идентификаторы никогда не повторялись в таблице. На простых уровнях проектирования смысл этого может быть не очень ясен, но если представить базу с более сложной структурой, то суть ставновится понятней. 
Простой пример: у вас две связанные таблицы: категория и подкатегория. Вы без учета связки удалили категорию, но её подкатегории остались. Если вы новой записи присвоете идентификатор старой категории, то автоматически подкатегории встретят нового "папу" с распростёртыми руками. И с этого момента начнется каша.
Поэтому не заморачивайтесь, чисел хватит на всех ))

Comment: А еще можно вспомнить поисковики. По-моему, можно и в баню отправиться, если в индексе будет ссылка на запись, а по этому id запись другая.

Comment: в приличной базе данных такие вещи решаются на уровне ссылочной целостности - удалите категорию - каскадно удалятся подкатегории

Comment: renegator, я всего лишь привел пример взятый "с потолка", а вы прям так серьёзно к этому подходите ))

Answer (score 1):

в диалекте T-SQL, поправите если что. это можно вставить в триггер

```
SELECT TOP 1 t1.id+1
FROM [table] t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN [table] t2 ON t2.id = (t1.id+1)
WHERE   t2.id IS NULL
ORDER BY 1
```

ЗЫ. Но сама идея ..но конечно

Answer (score 0):

А в чем смысл данного заморачивания? можно поподробней про вашу проблему - может выход в другом можно найти?

Да в том что есть незанятые id никакой проблемы нет - так уж устроена БД. Не нада на счет етого заморачиватся

Comment: Дело в том, допустим добавляются записи с id 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 Через некоторое время записи с 3 и 4 я удаляю... Я хочу, Чтобы когда я потом буду добавлять записи, нумерация id начиналась с 3.. Когда опять добавляю запись - с 4... затем с 8, 9 Тоесть с первого не занятого id